# Go to a view and trigger a $scope function with ui-router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I realize this ask is for a hack, but here is the motivation:

- I am designing a "shortcut" view for my rather complex app. Users want to trigger functions inside different views.
- Different users have different opinions on useful shortcuts
- For example, one user may want to define a shortcut that "goes to view `app.montage` and triggers `$scope.toggleInfo()`"
- Another user may want to define a completely different shortcut that invokes a function 3 levels deep inside an existing view's UI

So bottomline, can I devise something like:
`$state.go('state name')` && then initiate function inside that state?

I know I can define URL routes, but its a rather complex app and its easier to be able to "trigger" actions if I can.

Comment: What decides which user gets what action? Button clicks, user preference settings or other??

Comment: It will be a predefined list of available actions - imagine the shortcut page to be a series of buttons, where a user defines what each button will do. They will select from a list. Each list will be "state name and a function that is already available in that state"

Comment: Well one option is using url params and pass those through using `$state.go()` . You might also need a service and use a resolve based on params. A plunker demo that shows what you are trying to accomplish would help. Read `$state.go` docs, will see you can pass data as second argument

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$stateProvider.state('users', {
    url: '/users',
    controller: 'UsersCtrl',
    params: {
        obj: null
    }
})
```

```
function UserCtrl($stateParams,$scope) {
    console.log($stateParams);
    $stateParams.obj && $stateParams.obj.toggleInfo && $scope.toggleInfo();
}
```

```
$state.go('users', {obj:{toggleInfo: true});
```

For more information, see [UI-Router Wiki - Using Parameters without Specifying Them in State URLs](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#using-parameters-without-specifying-them-in-state-urls).

Comment: Excellent. I wanted parameter passing without URL routes. Is there any way the "$stateParams.obj.toggleInfo && $scope.toggleInfo()" can be customized to "$stateParams.obj.fnName && $scope.<fnName>()" where <fnName> get dereferenced to the function name passed?

Comment: This worked!
`stateParams.shortcut &&  $stateParams.shortcut.fn && 
    $scope[$stateParams.shortcut.fn]();`